# Apply style to only one element of a map of elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to imitate a behaviour of a checked componenet applied to a map of divs. I am mapping displayName and imageUrl of an array of elements called price. On click of the div, in handleProductSelect function, I would like only the clicked div to be highlighted, however they all become highlighted, which makes sense, because I am collectively making a change in the style.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            borderColor: 'white',
}
}


    handleProductSelect() {
        const { borderColor } = this.state;
        let newBorderColour = borderColor === 'white' ? 'blue' : 'white';
        this.setState({
            borderColor: newBorderColour,
        })
    }

(price.map(p =>
                    <div key={p.productId}>
                        <div
                            style={{ 
                                borderRadius: '10%',
                                borderStyle: 'solid',
                                padding: '10px',
                                marginBottom: 10,
                                borderColor: this.state.borderColor,
                             }}
                            onClick={this.handleProductSelect(p.productId)}>
                            <div>{p.displayName}</div><br />
                            <div>{p.imageUrl !== '' ? p.imageUrl : <img style={{ width: '100px', height: '50px' }} src={"https://source.unsplash.com/200/150"} />}</div><br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))
}
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to make only the clicked element highlighted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the id that you are passing to your `handleProductSelect` function and save it to the state. You can use it in the `render` method, to figure which one is the clicked element and apply the appropriate style to it

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            borderColor: 'white',
            active_id: null
        };
}


    handleProductSelect(productId) {
        const { borderColor } = this.state;
        let newBorderColour = borderColor === 'white' ? 'blue' : 'white';
        this.setState({
            borderColor: newBorderColour,
            active_id: productId
        })
    }

render {
return(
    (price.map(p =>
        <div key={p.productId}>
            <div
                style={{ 
                    borderRadius: '10%',
                    borderStyle: 'solid',
                    padding: '10px',
                    marginBottom: 10,
                    borderColor: ( p.productId === this.state.active_id ? this.state.borderColor : 'white'),
                 }}
                onClick={this.handleProductSelect.bind(this, p.productId)}>
                <div>{p.displayName}</div><br />
                <div>{p.imageUrl !== '' ? p.imageUrl : <img style={{ width: '100px', height: '50px' }} src={"https://source.unsplash.com/200/150"} />}</div><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    ))
    }
)}
```

Comment: thank you, but this somehow send me into an infinite loop, with the following warning: `react-dom.development.js:509 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`

Comment: WOW, I'm sorry for that, check the change. You shouldn't execute the function in `onSubmit`, which is what was happening

Comment: thank you, I am getting another error inside handleProductSelect, `Cannot read property 'borderColor' of undefined`

Comment: You can also pass `this` to `bind` like so `this.handleProductSelect.bind(this, p.productId)`

Comment: I am also already binding this function in the constructor, please, see I updated the question as well

Comment: try that, you should pass `this` to the `bind` function

Answer (score 0):

Here I have fixes the syntax of *ternary operator style css, and fatArrow function call with onClick event*

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            borderColor: 'white',
            active_id: null
        };
}


    handleProductSelect(productId) {
        const { borderColor } = this.state;
        let newBorderColour = borderColor === 'white' ? 'blue' : 'white';
        this.setState({
            borderColor: newBorderColour,
            active_id: productId
        })
    }

render {
return(
    (price.map(p =>
        <div key={p.productId}>
            <div
                style={{ 
                    borderRadius: '10%',
                    borderStyle: 'solid',
                    padding: '10px',
                    marginBottom: 10,
                    p.productId === this.state.active_id ? { borderColor: this.state.borderColor} : {borderColor : 'white'}
                 }}


                onClick={(p)=> this.handleProductSelect(p.productId)}>
                <div>{p.displayName}</div><br />
                <div>{p.imageUrl !== '' ? p.imageUrl : <img style={{ width: '100px', height: '50px' }} src={"https://source.unsplash.com/200/150"} />}</div><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    ))
    }
)}
```